# Visual Studio 2008 Help System

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is there any way to make the Visual Studio 2008 help system more object aware when querying a property?

Let me explain.  In good old fashioned VB6, if I create a winsock control, and type winsock1.close and then highlight the close and hit f1, it brings up the help for the close property for a winsock control - and not the close property for files, or serial ports, or anything else.  The help system is intelligent enough to look back at the object type.  Or if the property is so generic that everything has it, it brings up the generic help and an applies to list.

This does not seem to be the case in Visual Studio 2008.  I cannot count the number of times I have typed object.property, highlighted the property and tapped F1, to be presented with that property from a totally unrelated object type which is inherently different.  It is like it finds the first instance of that property name in the help system and spews that back.  So then I swear profusely, enter the object name in the search, get the object, scroll to the property, and click on it.

Is there no way to make the help system as intelligent as it was back in the VB6 days.  I know VB6 sucks compared to Visual Studio 2008, but that was one thing they had correct!  Or am I missing something basic (pun intended) here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to post bug to [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com)? I think that it is IDE bug and should be fixed.

Comment: I've been an MSDN member for years - but never tried that.  I just copied and pasted my comment from here as a suggestion there.  Thanks for the tip.  We'll see what happens.

Comment: Here it is - let's get em to fix it!  Thanks for the advice.
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=477399